# Transfer data using UDP across port 20002 over 3g internet, android?

Tags: android, udp, port

I am developing a  android app through which I am sending data  through UDP port 20001 and get data to PORT 20002.
This app is working fine over WiFi, but it can not send data through UDP port 20001 over mobile data/internet.
Please help me out with a sample code.

Comment: what is the ip that you are using to send data?

Comment: if application runs on the same network/IP data transfer happens but not on different IP's

Comment: yes, this is how it works, now to send data out from your local network you need the ip of that system.

Comment: Define 'can not send data'. What happens instead? Define your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-20001.asp

google the port numbers.
port 20001 and 20002 seems to have something to do with trojans.
Perhaps it is blocked by the device